# Is vbo respect the order set by view while performing operation? or is there a way to tell it to perform in same order as result

Tags: views

In a simple vbo I needed to set field_serial_no to row no of view's result. By default view result is ordered by title in ascending and order cannot be modified (not exposed to user).
When these entities are passed to VBO, will it be aware of order of entities always? if yes I can directly access the index and save it in field_no. I not is there any method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually depends an the specific action. VBO gives the data in the same order as the view. But the action can rearrange the id's. Although most just process it the way they got it.